# How to do Login with Firebase integration in .NET MAUI?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to login with integration to social networks, more specifically to Google in .NET MAUI. I've done it with Xamarin Forms and it worked perfectly, however, in MAUI a standard error is occurring:

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   LoginWithRedes (net6.0-ios), LoginWithRedes (net6.0-maccatalyst), LoginWithRedes (net6.0-windows10.0.19041) C:\MAUI\LoginWithRedes\LoginWithRedes\Platforms\Android\GoogleManager.cs

[Libraries not being recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGm4s.png)

[Packages I added to the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Ad6.png)

Code of the GoogleManager.CS Class where the standard error occurs to me:

`[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GoogleManager))]
namespace LoginWithRedes.Platforms.Android
{
public class GoogleManager : Java.Lang.Object, IGoogleManager, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
{
public static GoogleApiClient _googleApiClient { get; set; }
public static GoogleManager Instance { get; private set; }

```
    public bool IsLogedIn { get; set; }

    Context _context;

    public GoogleManager()
    {
        _context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void Login()
    {
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                                                         .RequestEmail()
                                                         .Build();
        _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder((_context).ApplicationContext)
            .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Profile))
            .Build();


        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(_googleApiClient);
        ((MainActivity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
        _googleApiClient.Connect();
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        var gsoBuilder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn).RequestEmail();

        GoogleSignIn.GetClient(_context, gsoBuilder.Build())?.SignOut();

        _googleApiClient.Disconnect();

    }

    public void OnAuthCompleted(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            IsLogedIn = true;
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();

        }
        else
        {



        }
    }`
```

[OnActivityResult method that I implemented in MainActivity class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHjah.png)

If anyone can help me with this error, I would be very grateful.
Note: I'm new to Xamarin and Maui.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having a hard time getting anything to work with Google login. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199100/net-maui-android-app-how-to-get-email-and-profile-from-google-login

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you get any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also new to Maui, and in my experience, these errors were caused by using native Xamarin libraries in Maui. Xamarin targets each platform separately using separate nuget packages. Maui's combined 1-project architecture means you need to use packages that work for both at once.

At least when I was getting started a few months ago, these weren't readily available. Firebase client was not yet released for .NET 6.0 (Multiplatform by default).

Things may have changed since then. But I had great success using Firebase with this plugin https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase. It wraps up the platform specific libraries into a single project API, with a really easy to use c# interface. You can use await and stuff as you would expect. Calling the native APIs was difficult, and required a lot of code duplication. This plugin saves a lot of time, and I haven't yet run into any problems.

The documentation on the plugin is a bit sparse, but hey, it's free and works.