# .Net Maui Android app how to get email and profile from Google login

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-maui

I tried WebAuthenticator and it doesn't work.

I also tried using the deprecated GoogleApiClient with this method and the value is always null.

```
var person = PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)
```

I even tried adding email and profile scopes to my Google Fit Auth, but I can't get the email, profile etc...

I just tried this method, and it doesn't work either.

```
mSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.GetClient(this, options);
```

At this point, I'm stuck. Does anyone know how to get the user and profile information for the logged in user on a .Net Maui Android app???

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use the GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount method to request profile information for the currently signed in user. You can refer to this official Google documentation(legacy):https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed-in_user

Comment: Unfortunately, that method uses the GoogleSign method. All my packages are up to date. I'm getting this error. Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/AuthProxy

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working by creating my own LoginActivity.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

I'm calling the Activity using this code. It's running in an OnButtonClicked override in the LoginPage.xaml.cs file.

```
#if ANDROID

        var myIntent = new Android.Content.Intent(Platform.CurrentActivity, typeof(LoginActivity));
        Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

#endif
```

Finally, the OnCreate method in the LoginActivity calls SignOn() after this line of code executes.

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```